# React component don't see helper class. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing React tutorial about Tic Tac Toe game. I decided to create helper class Squares, to store 2D game field status.

```
  class Squares {
    constructor(size) {
      this._size = size
      this._squares = Array(size * size).fill(null)
    }
    square(row, col, value) {
      let position = (row - 1) * this._size + col - 1
      if (value !== undefined)
        this._squares[position] = value
      return this._squares[position]
    }
    get size() {
      return this._size
    }
    get copy() {
      let squares = new Squares(this._size)
      squares._squares = this._squares.slice()
      return squares
    }
  }
```

And use it in component's state, like this.

```
class Game extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      history: [{
        squares: new Squares(3)
      }],
      stepNumber: 0,
      xIsNext: true,
    }
  }
```

But then I got error. 
*"TypeError: Squares is not a constructor"*

Inside component Squares is undefined! But when I warp my class into function.

```
function Squares(size) {
  class Squares {
    ...
  }
  return new Squares(size)
}
```

.. component class can see my class now! 
But why? What difference between class and function?

Comment: It seems to work fine for me: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MoJYoO?editors=1011

Comment: Yes. I tested in my project and works OK. Are Game and Squares in the same file?

Comment: Problem solved. Helper class was after component class and that's why it didn't work properly. @croraf answer absolutly correct.

Comment: What confuses me is that in my setup I have Squares below Game and it still works. Probably because I use webpack and babel transpiling. But when I add "var a = Squares(1)" above Squares I get the same error as you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes should be defined before they are used, that's one of the differences between classes and functions.

Although I tested your classes, and it also works when Squares is below Game. This is probably due to some transpiling that happens in my setup.